# Error while adding "Widget" as field inside "State<NormalMenuState>" class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Purpose of such Implementation**

To show different views for the `admin` and `user` after sign in the `Scaffold body`.

**Error**

Below error is being shown while using `Widget` as field inside the `State<NormalMenuState>` class.

> '_NormalMenuState.widget' ('() → Widget') isn't a valid override of 'State.widget' ('() → NormalMenuState')

**Code**

```
class NormalMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userType;

  NormalMenu({this.userType});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(this.userType),
    );
  }
}

class NormalMenuState extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userType;

  NormalMenuState(this.userType);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NormalMenuState(userType: this.userType);
}

class _NormalMenuState extends State<NormalMenuState> {
  String appTitle = 'Welcome';
  final String userType;
  Widget widget; //<= `This line shows error`

  _NormalMenuState({this.userType});

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (this.userType == UserType.admin) {
      this.appTitle = "User Information";
      widget = UserInformation();
    } else {
      this.appTitle = "Pay Fair";
      widget = BookTicket();
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code:

```
abstract class State<T extends StatefulWidget> extends Diagnosticable {
  T get widget => _widget;
```

There is a `widget` getter for accessing related `StatefulWidget` class. The problem is not creating a Widget as a instance field, it's name as your error point out:

> '_NormalMenuState.widget' ('() → Widget') isn't a valid override of 'State.widget' ('() → NormalMenuState')

So change name of the variable:

```
Widget widget; => Widget myWidget;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change widget into displayWidget. because widget is already taken to retrieve value passed in NormalMenuState, e.g userType.